# Issue with UserForm ComboBox (partial string match)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am using a combobox on a userform, and I have added a list to it by using a dictionary (from Range).
I need the combobox to show partial string match as I am typing onto it, So I have used this code:

```
   With Me.ComboBox1
     .List = Filter(dic.Keys, .Text, True, vbTextCompare)   
      .DropDown                                               'Expand filter selection (reduced number of valid elements)
   End With
```

The above code works as it should, 
But if I selected any item (using drop down arrow on combobox itself) then I cannot list the combobox and I have to close the userform and open again. 
If I commented this line of the code ,the issue disappeared ,But I lost the partial string match.

```
.List = Filter(dic.Keys, .Text, True, vbTextCompare)
```

And this my full code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 
      If ComboBox1.value <> "False" And ComboBox1.value <> "" Then
 
'Partial String Match
 
       With Me.ComboBox1
          .List = Filter(dic.Keys, .Text, True, vbTextCompare)    'The issue on this line
          .DropDown                                               'Expand filter selection (reduced number of valid elements)
       End With
 
    End If
 
End Sub
```

As always, Thanks for all your interest to help.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74499926/how-to-prevent-userform-combobox-show-the-drop-down-list-if-the-item-is-only-one in case that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Create the next global variables on top of the form code module (in the declarations area):

```
Private dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Private noEvents As Boolean, boolNot As Boolean
```

2. The used dictionary **should be loaded prior to the following code event**. Probably, in `UserFor_Initialize` event. I suppose that your code already does that.

Please copy the  next event code instead of yours:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim chNo As Long, arr, chVar As String, mtch
      If ComboBox1.Value <> "False" And ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
         If Not noEvents Then
               With Me.ComboBox1
                  arr = filter(dict.Keys, .Text, True, vbTextCompare) 'place the filtered dict.keys in an array
                  mtch = Application.match(.Text, dict.Keys, 0)       'check if the combo value is A (whole) DICTIONARY KEY
                                                                                                          'or PART OF IT
                  If IsError(mtch) Then            'if part of the key:
                    .List = arr                    'load combo with filtered array
                    .DropDown                      'Expand filter selection (reduced number of valid elements)
                    noEvents = True: boolNot = True 'make boolean variables True
                  Else                              'if the whole key:
                    .List = dict.Keys: noEvents = False: boolNot = False 'load the dict keys and make bool vars False
                  End If
               End With
        Else
           If Not boolNot Then
                Me.ComboBox1.List = dict.Keys 'place the whole dict keys array
                boolNot = True                'not letting next time do do the same
            Else
                boolNot = False         'reinitialize bool variable
           End If
           noEvents = False             'reinitialize bool variable
         End If
    Else
       Me.cbE.List = dict.Keys          'when clearing combo value (nothing has been revealed by filterring, for instance)
    End If
End Sub
```

Take care that I did not use `dic` variable for the dictionary, I used `dict`...

Please, send some feedback after testing it. I did not test it intensively, but I think it should do what (I understood) you need...

Comment: Excellent works . I realized what you have meant by `It’s complex`.

Comment: Please, if you can help from your Great experience, https://superuser.com/questions/1762457/how-to-open-an-additional-hyperlink-word-document-on-local-intranet-and-bring